# Combine Row Cell for Repeater Record

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to combine the row cells when the campaign code and vehicle no are repeated as shown in below image. The result listed below is with gridview 20 page size

**Problem**

1. When the grid view page size is set with 2 for example, the row cell no longer combined. The result show each separated record.
2. If campaign code is sorted ascending/descending, the last record row cells will always not combine even though the campaign code and vehicle no are matched. Below image shown campaign code sorted in ascending. So when the campaign code is sorted descending, all the CMP002 are combined, while the last record of CMP001 will not be combined as shown in below image anymore.

**Code Behind**

```
 Private Sub GV_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GV.RowDataBound

    For rowIndex As Integer = GV.Rows.Count - 2 To 0 Step -1

        Dim gvRow As GridViewRow = GV.Rows(rowIndex)
        Dim gvPreviousRow As GridViewRow = GV.Rows(rowIndex + 1)
        Dim sCurrCampaignCode As String = GV.DataKeys(rowIndex).Values("CAMPAIGN_CODE")
        Dim sCurrVehicleNo As String = GV.DataKeys(rowIndex).Values("VEHICLE_NO")
        Dim sPreviousCampaignCode As String = GV.DataKeys(rowIndex + 1).Values("CAMPAIG_CODE")
        Dim sPreviousVehicleNo As String = GV.DataKeys(rowIndex + 1).Values("VEHICLE_NO")


        If sCurrCampaignCode = sPreviousCampaignCode AndAlso sCurrVehicleNo = sPreviousVehicleNo Then

            If sCurrCampaignCode = sPreviousCampaignCode Then

                    If gvPreviousRow.Cells(1).RowSpan < 2 Then
                        gvRow.Cells(1).RowSpan = 2
                        gvRow.Cells(2).RowSpan = 2
                        gvRow.Cells(3).RowSpan = 2
                    Else
                        gvRow.Cells(1).RowSpan = gvPreviousRow.Cells(1).RowSpan + 1
                        gvRow.Cells(2).RowSpan = gvPreviousRow.Cells(2).RowSpan + 1
                        gvRow.Cells(3).RowSpan = gvPreviousRow.Cells(3).RowSpan + 1
                    End If

                    gvPreviousRow.Cells(1).Visible = False
                    gvPreviousRow.Cells(2).Visible = False
                    gvPreviousRow.Cells(3).Visible = False
            End If

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution. Code have to be moved from RowDataBound to OnDataBound instead